# Can several buttons with background drawable behaviour be defined on the same button.xml archive?

Tags: android, xml, button, drawable

It's my first post. My question is the next. I have several buttons with personalized drawable image and I also want to define their behaviour.  For example:

**Layout xml**:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:background="@drawable/boton" />
```

**Drawable boton.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnanadir3"
      android:state_pressed="true" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnanadir2"
      android:state_focused="true" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnanadir1" />
</selector>
```

Till now it's Ok, but I want 9 buttons like this with different images and my question is if it exists any way to have all buttons on the same boton.xml or I have to have all buttons drawable behaviour in diferent boton.xml for each one? For example boton.xml, boton2.xml, boton3.xml... boton9.xml and have the drawable folder with 9 boton.xml archives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the 9 different xml files, since the xml file is where the images are specified.

Comment: Thanks GreyBeardedGeek. This way I did. No choose then.